# To CurrentThread.Abort or not to CurrentThread.Abort

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've seen a number of examples that have a thread procedure that looks like this.

```
    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        while (serviceStarted)
        {
            // do some work

            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
```

Is the `Abort()` really necessary at the end?

There are number of arguments against calling `Abort()`

1. Once the procedure exited - it is expected it has already cleaned up after itself.
2. Calling `Abort()` throws an exception, which is generally more resource intensive than just exiting a procedure.

I'd like to read an explanation for why this is or isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `Thread.Abort()` does raise an exception, and if you're writing code that will be re-used (or part of a base library) it's difficult for other developers to handle `ThreadAbortExcpetion`s.

It's explained in this article about [Reliability Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228970(VS.80).aspx).

I've always heard that calling [`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) is a better way to do it, if you can wait until the thread is completed processing.

I don't know if anyone thinks it's a good practice.  It can cause deadlocks (because unmanaged resources aren't properly cleaned up when you throw an exception)

Here's [another article about it](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation), and other methods to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Once the loop exits, the thread will terminate on its own. There is not need to abort the thread.

The `CurrentThread.Abort` is not only superfluous, but genuinely harmful since it raises a `ThreadAbortException`. If another thread attempts to `Join()` your service loop thread, it will have to handle an exception unnecessarily. Your best bet is just to delete the line `CurrentThread.Abort()`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Abort()` on one's own thread is safe, but apart from that it should generally be avoided because you can't be sure other threads will terminate gracefully. In many cases you don't need to abort the thread. Just let it finish and it will be reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. But I would advise against it since such a statement would prevent the method from being reused easily.

Answer (score 0):

A thread will naturally self-terminate when it has no further work to do: when the logic it was executing completes.

`Thread.Abort()` causes a `ThreadAbortException` to be thrown on the current thread with the explicit purpose of rapidly terminating all execution on the thread. This is one of the special .NET exceptions which is "uncatchable": you can write a catch block but the exception will continue to be thrown after the catch block completes. This ensures there is no way an instruction to abort a thread can be stopped by subsequent user code.

Calling `Thread.Abort()` is generally seen as bad practice as there are more graceful ways to terminate the logic you are executing. Cancellation is better handled using a `CancellationToken`.