# error occured in window service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

This is my first window service that I am writing, I need some help in writing it, I am trying to use single thread so that one thread can start the service
and the other thread can take care of calling the functions that does the database work. I am also using a timer so that this service only runs once a day below is my code

The reason i am posting this question is whenever I tried to install this service, it is throwing an error saying "fatal error occure", it doen't give me any details.

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        Thread workerThread;

    public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(WorkerFunction);
            workerThread = new Thread(st);
            serviceStarted = true;
            workerThread.Start();
        }
     protected override void OnStop()
        {
            // flag to tell the worker process to stop
            serviceStarted = false;

            // give it a little time to finish any pending work
            workerThread.Join(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

     private void WorkerFunction()
        {
                while (serviceStarted)
                {

                  EventLog.WriteEntry("Service working",
                     System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                  // yield
                  if (serviceStarted)
                  {
                     Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 20000, 0));
                  }
                  timer1.Enabled = true;
                  timer1.Start();
                }

               // time to end the thread
               Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }


         private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                    if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                // does the actual work that deals with the database
                }

            timer1.Start();
            }
```

Comment: Is this a full code? usually error happen when service constructor, or OnStart method fire an exception, try to include OnStart method in try/catch block and log exception... also look into event log, it may give you some information about anhandled exceptions

Comment: And you're trying to install it using the command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to check:

1. Be sure that you have configured the `EventLog` source correctly ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source(v=vs.90).aspx)). My answer to [Windows service Started and stopped automatically, exception handling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521820/windows-service-started-and-stopped-automatically-exception-handling-issue/13522039) could be useful here also.
2. It looks like you are using a Windows Forms Timer - these require a UI message pump, which you won't have in a service ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.100).aspx)). You should instead investigate using the Timer class in the `System.Threading` namespace ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.100).aspx)).

In particular, you may find the using a `System.Threading.Timer` will simplify your code a great deal as this object will manage a bit more of the plumbing for you.

I would also advise against calling `Thread.Abort()`: it can be harmful and unpredictable, and in your case it doesn't appear that you need to use it at all. See [To CurrentThread.Abort or not to CurrentThread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321779/to-currentthread-abort-or-not-to-currentthread-abort) and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz.aspx.